# Aligning multiple equation environments with cases

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, environments

I have some code that works but I wish to align the environments according to the descriptions. I've tried various combinations of `align`, `equation` and `cases`, but can't seem to find a functional solution.

```
\begin{equation}
  \textit{Initial conditions} \qquad \begin{cases}
  C\left(X,0\right) = S\left(X,0\right) = 0\\
  C\left(0,T\right) = 1
  \end{cases}
  \label{eq:dimensionless_initcond}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \textit{Continuous injection} \qquad  C\left(0,T\right) = 1 \label{eq:dimensionless_continuous}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \textit{Finite injection} \qquad C\left(0,T\right) = \begin{cases}
  1 \text{ for } 0 < T < T_0\\
  0 \text{ for } T_0 < T < \infty
  \end{cases}
  \label{eq:dimensionless_finite}
\end{equation}
```

Optimal case would be to have the environments such that both descriptions and equations are left aligned as seen in my badly done `mspaint` picture here:
[image: optimal case]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial thought would be to place everything in an `align` environment as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand{\mytext}[1]{\makebox[1.25in][l]{#1}\qquad}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \mytext{Initial conditions} 
  & \begin{cases}
      C\left(X,0\right) = S\left(X,0\right) = 0\\
      C\left(0,T\right) = 1
    \end{cases}
    \label{eq:dimensionless_initcond}
  \\[2ex]
  \mytext{Continuous injection} 
  &
    C\left(0,T\right) = 1 
    \label{eq:dimensionless_continuous}
  \\[2ex]
  \mytext{Finite injection} 
  &
  C\left(0,T\right) 
    = 
    \begin{cases}
      1 \text{ for } 0 < T < T_0\\
      0 \text{ for } T_0 < T < \infty
    \end{cases}
  \label{eq:dimensionless_finite}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since the `align` environment wants to make the material in the first column *right aligned*, I create a box to wrap the text there `\mytext` which you can format as you want.  It uses a `\makebox` whose syntax is:

```
\makebox[<width>][<alignment>]{<text>}
```

The `<alignment>` here can be *left* `l`, *right* `r`, or *center* which is the default.

Comment: Implementing your solution it gives a lot of Undefined control sequence errors when I added the \newcommand in my preamble file. It works perfectly with the \newcommand in the specific .tex file itself however. Not as pretty code-wise, but it works :) cheers!